# My Lat/Lng query with google maps V2 gives 9 different results why?

Tags: google-maps, gps, location, double, google-maps-markers

I am not sure of what to do or how to proceed. I know I have the right position I can see it in the textview. When query is made,it is made like this "http://maps.google.com/maps?q=loc:" + lat + "," + lng   );

One of the the result that is returned by google maps is correct. The others I don't want. How can you have multiple results for something that is supposed to be unique.

Thanks for any help

Mike

Comment: What is the `V2` in the title?  What it the specific location that is returning multiple results?

Comment: V2 is version 2 API Google Maps and yes specific location is returning multiple results.

Comment: The [no longer available v2 javascript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/reference)?  That should not be used for any development, but it isn't consistent with your question.

Comment: I am not using javascript , I am writing the code in Java for android development google maps v2. I get lat lng info from a marker , then I want to query that location. Perhaps it has something to do with getLatitudeE6() / 1E6 + "," + Location.getLongitudeE6() / 1E6; or just query statement is my best guess.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved turns out that query statement was the issue.